# How to use PHImageManager with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uicollectionview, photosframework

I am new to iOS development and having a hard time getting my head around the concept of the PHImageManager. I read somewhere that it can return a thumbnail sized image and a real sized one as well but I was not able to figure out how.

In my app I am showing a collection view with the images from the camera roll. If the user taps on one of the images (cells) that image is passed to another ViewController for viewing in a larger size. I achieve this by using a segue which gets the selected cell's `imageview.image` property and pushes that `UIImage` to the next ViewController.

**My problem is:** How can I configure the image manager to get thumbnail size images for the collection view and load the real size of the images when they are selected? Right now I am using a `targetSize` of 40x40 for loading the images into the collection view but this way they loose their resolution when opened in the next ViewController. If I use the real size of the images for the collection view however, it takes ages for it to load up. Can anyone give me a solution to this problem?

Also: I read something about PHCachingImageManager...does it have anything to do with solving my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this code helps you.

If you done it with my code then please pick my answer thanks.

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

                let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                options.networkAccessAllowed = true
                options.synchronous = false
                PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(assets?[indexPath.row] as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSizeMake(40, 40), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: options) { (image, info) -> Void in
                    if (image != nil) {
                        (cell as! PhotoCell).image = image
                    }
                }




        }
```